# Change Cell's Background color on dynamic JTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, java-7

I have a table in Java which contains the content from directories. I have created 5 comboBoxes which navigate the user into folders and then it creates a JTable with the contents of the selected folder, like filename, date, creator, etc. In the 6th column of the table I have some string values and depending on each value I want to change the background color of this cell. 
Here is the last comboBox in which I start the JTable.

Comment: Quick note: `catch(NullPointerException n){}`? You should never catch a NPE, and this suggests you have something seriously wrong with this code.

Comment: If you need further help you will want to create and post a valid [mcve], a new small program posted in your question as code-formatted text.

Comment: I now see that a MCVE was requested in your [previous unanswered question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44279125/add-selected-data-from-jtable-to-lst-file), but that you never provided one (just like you don't here). Please don't ignore these requests if you want a decent answer to your questions. We're requesting this information for a reason -- so that we can fully understand your code, your problem and your question.

Comment: That for loop in the prepareRenderer doesn't look right, if only I had MCVE code to test it on...

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels I just added the example code. Hope it will be easier now.

Comment: Your code does not compile for me and has too many compilation errors. Please fix.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry to be blunt, but your attempt to catch NPE `catch(NullPointerException n){}`-- is so very wrong -- never do this, but instead fix the bugs that might be causing the NPE to occur.

As for your problem, you're not overloading the actual method. Your method signature:

```
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int rowIndex)
```

Does not match the actual method signature:

```
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer,
                             int row,
                             int column)
```

as per the [JTable API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#prepareRenderer-javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer-int-int-), you're missing the 3rd parameter, the column int parameter.

This is why you should *always* prepend overridden methods with the `@Override` annotation. Had you done this:

```
@Override   // this will cause the compiler to complain that this isn't an override
public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int rowIndex)
```

And your for loop in this method looks quite suspect. I'd get rid of it since the renderer should render only the cell that is specified by the row and column indices.

e.g.,

```
DefaultTableModel listModel = new DefaultTableModel();
JTable table1 = new JTable(listModel){

    @Override // don't forget this!
    public Component prepareRenderer(TableCellRenderer renderer, int rowIndex, int columnIndex) {
        JComponent component = (JComponent) super.prepareRenderer(renderer, i, columnIndex);
        int lastRow = listModel.getRowCount();
        // this will likely set the whole row. If you only want to set only a specific cell, then 
        // you'll need to first check the columnIndex.
        if (getValueAt(rowIndex, 6).toString().contains("yellow")) {
            component.setBackground(Color.RED);
        } else {
            component.setBackground(null);  // turn color back to default
        }
        return component;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You should not extend `JTable` but `DefaultTableCellRenderer` and set that as the default renderer in your Table:

```
public class TableRendererExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TableCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTableCellRenderer(){
            @Override
            public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected,
                    boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
                Component rendererComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
                rendererComponent.setBackground("value2".equals(value)?Color.RED:Color.WHITE);
                return rendererComponent;
            }
        };
        TableModel tableModel= new DefaultTableModel(10, 3){
            @Override
            public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
                return "value"+new Random().nextInt(4);
            }       
        };
        JTable jTable = new JTable(tableModel);
        jTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, renderer);
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jTable);
    }
}
```

---

---

> Likely this is a better long-term solution since it also allows the OP to set the cell renderer for a specific column. – Hovercraft Full Of Eels

Even better you don't need to know the column index in advance when you overwrite `getColumnClass()` in `TableModel`:

same Renderer class for all columns:

```
class DefaultTableCellRendererBackground extends DefaultTableCellRenderer {
    private final Color highlightColor;

    DefaultTableCellRendererBackground(Color highlightColor) {
        this.highlightColor = highlightColor;
    }

    @Override
    public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus,
            int row, int column) {
        Component rendererComponent = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row,
                column);
        rendererComponent.setBackground(highlightColor);
        return rendererComponent;
    }
}
```

TableModel returning different ColumnClasses each run:

```
final class DefaultTableModelExtension extends DefaultTableModel {
    private final List<Class<?>> columnClass;

    DefaultTableModelExtension(int rowCount, int columnCount, List<Class<?>> columnClass) {
        super(rowCount, columnCount);
        this.columnClass = columnClass;
        Collections.shuffle(this.columnClass);
    }

    @Override
    public Class<?> getColumnClass(int col) {
        return columnClass.get(col);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getValueAt(int arg0, int arg1) {
        return "value" + new Random().nextInt(4);
    }
}
```

Types to be returned:

```
interface TagRed {}

interface TagBlue {}

interface TagYellow {}
```

usage (run multiple times...):

```
public class TableRendererExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JTable jTable = new JTable();
        jTable.setDefaultRenderer(TagRed.class, new DefaultTableCellRendererBackground(Color.RED));
        jTable.setDefaultRenderer(TagBlue.class, new DefaultTableCellRendererBackground(Color.BLUE));
        jTable.setDefaultRenderer(TagYellow.class, new DefaultTableCellRendererBackground(Color.YELLOW));

        List<Class<?>> columnClass = Arrays.asList(TagRed.class, String.class, TagBlue.class, TagRed.class, String.class,
                TagYellow.class, TagBlue.class);
        jTable.setModel(new DefaultTableModelExtension(10, columnClass.size(), columnClass));
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, jTable);
    }
}
```